# Don't lightyears define objective time?

Tags: special-relativity, time, units

I've hard things like "Time and space are relative, so if a rocket leaves Earth at a relativistic speed, their time will be slowed down from our perspective, but from theirs, the EARTH is moving at a relativistic speed away from them, and OUR time is slowing down, and both are right because there is no universal clock of objective time!"

However, if a 1g relativistic rocket were to go to say, Thuban, 303 light years away, it may seem like it was only 11 years for them, but wouldn't they look back at Earth 303 light years away, and have to say, "Well, we travelled 303 lightyears, therefore, 303 years must have passed on Earth."

If light is the same speed in all frames of reference, wouldn't that mean 303 years must have also passed on Thuban since they left Earth? Doesn't that make light and light years a universal clock of objective time?

Comment: But if we can look at another star and say "That light left that star 303 year ago" wouldn't the astronaut have to say "That's Earth 303 and three years ago, not the present"?

Comment: Why would the traveler say "we travelled 303 lightyears" when in fact (in his own frame of course) he has remained stationary while the earth travelled 11 light years?

Comment: Wouldn't the Earth be 303 lightyears away from Thuban? The space wouldn't stay contracted forever, would it?

Comment: At the moment when Thuban passes the rocket, earth is 11 light years from the rocket.  A minute later, earth is a little farther from the rocket/Thuban.  The distance changes constantly, but the only distance that's relevant to your question is the distance at the time when the rocket and Thuban cross paths --- at which time just a hair over 11 years have passed on earth.

Comment: And if the rocket stopped at Thuban? Would the slowing down process cause the distance from Earth to lengthen from the ship's perspective?

Comment: In the frame of the moving ship, earth is 11 light years away and about 11 years have passed on earth since the rocket departed.  In the frame of the stopped ship, earth is 303 light years away and about 303 years have passed on earth since the rocket departed.    Both statements remain true whether the ship happens to be moving or not.  Nothing "lengthens".

Comment: I'm sure I've posted this analogy before somewhere, but it's relevant here:  If you're standing in New York facing west, Los Angeles is 3000 miles straight ahead in your frame.  If you turn 90 degrees and face north, Los Angeles is 3000 miles to the left in your new frame.  Saying that the distance to earth "lengthens" when you change frames by stopping your ship is **exactly** analogous to saying that Los Angeles "moves" several thousand miles when you change frames by turning 90 degrees.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to draw a spacetime diagram representing this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it may seem like it was only 11 years for them, but wouldn't they look back at Earth 303 light years away, and have to say, "Well, we travelled 303 lightyears, therefore, 303 years must have passed on Earth."

They can say that, but what does it mean, empirically?

Earth isn't a sphere in spacetime; it's a cylinder with a spherical cross-section. The time on Earth when 11 years passed since the rocket ship left is one part of that tube, and the time when 303 years passed is another part. The rocket ship when it arrives at Thuban is nowhere near either of those locations, or any other part of Earth's worldtube, so why would they say that Earth is at some particular part of its worldtube when they arrive? Earth doesn't move along its worldtube. It is its worldtube.

You can establish a time standard that covers both Earth and Thuban, and we might do that if we were sending people there. You can then say that at the same time that the rocket arrives at Thuban, something happens on Earth, such as the celebration of some particular new year. But those events are synchronous only by the time standard that we defined. Nature doesn't care about human time standards.

Answer (score 3):

Distance is observer-dependent.

Given two observers with a relative velocity, if one of them measures a distance $s$ and a relative velocity $v$, the other will measure a distance $$s' = s/ \gamma$$ where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand in the extreme case: if you were on a light speed ship that accelerated instantly to the speed of light, assuming you and your ship did not turn to atomized mush, whenever you looked back at the Earth, you would see the Earth as it was when you left no matter how long you had been traveling, because you are traveling with the light from the image of the Earth that left at the same time you did.

In that case, if the distance you had traveled was 303 light years, your image of the Earth would be 303 light-years away BUT that image of the Earth will have been the image of it when you left, including the people standing on it waving good-bye.

And the trip would have seen instantaneous to you (this last part is the one I find difficult to wrap my head around).

Therefore upon arrival, you would perceive that no time has passed for you or the Earth. However, the Earth would have perceived that 303-years have passed by the time it can see you arrive at your destination.

If you sit there, you can watch how things played out on Earth after you left (i.e. you can watch the past).

If you turned around and traveled back, upon your return you would find an Earth 606-years older than when you left when the time that had passed for you was the time you spent looking back after arrival plus the time it took for you to turn the ship around.

Answer (score 0):

You are overlooking the relativity of simultaneity.

You cannot say absolutely how far away a moving object is at a given moment, because its position depends upon time, and time is not absolute.

To be more specific, two observers who are moving relative to each other will have different planes of simultaneity. What constitutes 'now' for each of the observers will be a different slice of spacetime. So if you ask each observer how far away is Thuban 'now', you will get two different answers, because each is refering to the position of Thuban at a different time.

Suppose a spaceship travelling at close to the speed of light were to pass the Earth in the direction of Thuban. You ask its captain as it passes how far away is Thuban. She will say it is about ten light years away. That is because the slice of spacetime that corresponds to 'now' for the spaceship is tilted at almost 45 degrees to the plane of simultaneity for the Earth, so from the Earth perspective the captain seems to be predicting where Thuban will be a few hundred years in the Earth's future rather than where it is 'now' in Earth time.

Likewise, when the spaceship passes Thuban ten years later (by ship time) and asks the Thubans 'where is the Earth now?' they will say three hundred light years away. The captain will disagree and say that the Earth is 'now' only about ten light years away. That again is because the captain is referring to a much earlier 'now' than the now of the Thubans.

If the ship decelerates to be stationary wrt Earth at Thuban, then Earth will 'now' be 303 light years away. To another spaceship passing Thuban at some other speed, Earth 'now' will be yet another distance away. The distance to Earth depends entirely on your frame of reference.

All a light year can tell you in an absolute sense is how far light will travel in a year in your rest frame.

All the famous so-called paradoxes of relativity- the twin paradox, Bell's spaceship paradox, the ladder-in-the-barn paradox- arise where people fail to take the relativity of simultaneity into account.